# How to make python-isort consider my pypackage.toml configuration?

Tags: python, python-poetry, isort

I'm using `isort` toll to sort import statements in python.

I configured everything in my `pyproject.toml` file which looks like:

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
multi_line_output = 5
atomic = true
include_trailing_comma = true
lines_after_imports = 2
lines_between_types = 1
use_parentheses = true
src_paths = ["src/mypackage", "tests"]
filter_files = true
known_first_party = "mypackage"
```

Yet, when lauching `isort .`, it sorted my `docs/config.py` file, meaning it did not consider the `src_paths` option.

Question: **how to make it consider the `.toml` file configuration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [that's not what `src_paths` is for](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#src-paths):

> Add an explicitly defined source path (modules within src paths have their imports automatically categorized as first_party).

You'll want [`skip`](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#skip) instead to ignore given paths.

Comment: Oh, ok. By the way, do you know how to specify the configuration file to the command line? Is it possible? I was wondering that as vscode requires all parameters and I don't want to type it twice.

Comment: What do you mean with "vscode requires all parameters"?

Comment: I need to give something like `"python.sortImports.args": ["-rc", "--atomic"],` to vscode. here, the `atomic` parameter was given, as an example.  But I found the solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5840).